# Re-assemble vintage (1960's) Schlage front door knob assembly

Tags: doors, lock

Refurbishing front door of 1960's MCM house. Fully functional brass Schlage door lock with large rosettes on front and back.  I began to disassemble to clean by pushing on collar pinhole closest to rosette. Pushed and this trigger me being able to pull and remove the inner door knob. I wanted to confirm I could re-assemble at this point before going further... Now stuck in re-assembly in that the pinhole I pushed in on knob collar closest to the rosette seems stuck now and I'm not able to depress to slide door knob back into place.  If anyone has a suggestion would be very welcome?  Thanks!

[image]